# How can I join three tables in Bookshelf.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I read the Bookshelf documentation related to `through`, but, but I can't found out how I should proceed. I have three tables named in a different convention than Bookshelf uses. Basically, a Group has many Users through Profile. The last one that makes the connection.

```
Table Name: User
   - id_user
   - username
   - password

Table Name: Profile
  - id_user
  - id_group

Table Name: Group
 - id_group
 - name
 - description
 - status
```

My group model is like so:

```
module.export = BookShelf.model('Group', {
  tableName: 'pats_grupos',

  users: function() {
    return this.hasMany('User').through('Profile');
  }
});
```

Taking in consideration that my tables don't follow the `_id` convention (but instead, the `id_` one), how can I tell Bookshelf to work with my custom table naming pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [Bookshelf's `idAttribute` documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-idAttribute), when not using the default 'id' you must change your models to explicitly declare the id attribute used. Like:

```
module.export = BookShelf.model('Group', {
  tableName: 'pats_grupos',
  idAttribute: 'id_group',

  users: function() {
    return this.hasMany('User').through('Profile');
  }
});
```

And since your foreign keys are also not following Bookshelf default naming you **may** have to declare them explicitly on the [`through()` call](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-through) too. Something like:

```
//...
users: function() {
  return this
    .hasMany('User')
    .through('Profile', 'id_user', 'id_group');
}
//...
```